# signedcms.ComputeSignature() function

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

I am using `signedcms.ComputeSignature()` function but it requires **private key** from the certificate but it is not accessible. Is there any other way to make a `p7s signature` without using this function?

Answer (score 0):

No, without a private key you cannot create a signature. If you could do that then the authentication and/or non-repudiation properties of the signature would be lost, rendering the signature algorithm useless.